# C# json parse string inside 2nd curly brackets {X{Y}}

Tags: c#, json, string

I try to parse string inside 2nd curly brackets using C# / json

String looks like this:

```
{"R27":{"DEVX":0.1346224}}
```

My aim is read value of DEVX, which is **0.1346224**

I've tried:

```
var joR = JObject.Parse(R);
string R27 = joR["R27"].ToString();
```

RETURNS : {"DEVX":0.1346224}}

```
string R27 = joR["DEVX"].ToString();
```

RETURNS ERROR

Is there way to get directly value "0.1346224" without playing with string?

Comment: Yes :-) But you need to work what object "DEVX" is a property of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - assuming you know the two names involved, you can just index twice, once to get the object for `R27`, then once within that object to get the value of `DEVX`:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\"R27\":{\"DEVX\":0.1346224}}";
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        double devX = (double) obj["R27"]["DEVX"];
        Console.WriteLine(devX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was close. Just small syntax error. Work well now.

Comment: @Lorean: Note the conversion to `double` rather than `string`, given that it *is* a numeric value in the JSON. You might want to convert it to a string later on of course, but I would keep it in its "natural" form for as long as you can. (In particular, don't convert it to a string and then parse it later...)

Comment: Thanks. This way even better.

Comment: @Lorean you need to mark this answer as correct so others will have benefit from it

Answer (score 2):

```
 var joR = JObject.Parse(R);
 var R27 = joR["R27"]["DEVX"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was close. Just small syntax error. Work well now.

Comment: Without toString, cast to double is a better solution